# CMD echo not printing value

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line

I'm trying to print the output value of a date variable in CMD

```
SET /a lastYear=%date:~6,4%-1 set lastDate=31/12/%lastYear% & echo %lastDate%
```

But echo prints %lastDate%

Someone knows why I can't see the value of the variable?

Regards

Comment: The value of variables are expanded before the line of code is executed. The echo needs to be on another line or you need to use delayed expansion.

Comment: Also you missed an ampersand, it should also be `& set lastDate=…`.

Comment: As a side note, what about letting powershell help? `powershell -nop (get-date).addyears(-1).tostring('31/12/yyyy')`